# UITableViewCell turns blue when scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am getting a really strange error and I can't figure out how to fix it: When I scroll around in my UITableView it will sometimes highlight a cell blue, even when I don't fully selected.

For example: 
-Cell 1-
-Cell 2-
-Cell 3-
-Cell 4-
If I put my finger down on Cell 2 and scroll to Cell 4 it will leave Cell 2 highlighted, even though didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is never fired.

Any ideas?

EDIT
Added code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    
    static NSString *cellId = @"StyleDefault";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId] autorelease];
    }
    
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell One";
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [cell setAccessoryView:nil];
    
    return cell;
```

Comment: could you show us the cell creation code in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: please tell us what you do exactly in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate?

Answer (score 1):

FIXED IT!

My solution was two parts:

1) In cellForRowAtIndexPath: put "cell.selected = NO;", which fixes the problem of if the cell gets touched down on then goes off screen (scrolling).

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

static NSString *cellId = @"StyleDefault";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell One";
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[cell setAccessoryView:nil];

//Here:
cell.selected = NO;

return cell;
```

2) Put "[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];" into didSelectRowAtIndexPath: instead of what I used to have "[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:NO];" which was wrong on so many levels.

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Hopefully that helps others that have this issue. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following while creating cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell = Your allocation.

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

I guess you need to also please have look at the UIViewTable Property for Touch i.e. Delay Content Touches and Cancellable Content Touches.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This gets rid of the selection when I'm scrolling, but unfortunately makes it so that if the user actually selects the row it doesn't turn blue.

Answer (score 0):

Override -tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: in your UITableView delegate, and return nil for everything just to make sure you're not allowing it to select the rows.

Comment: I guess he wants the cell to be selectable. His point is when you scroll the view.

Comment: This doesn't allow me to select the row at all